# QGIS atlas with chart

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-variable, dataplotly

I use the the atlas in QGIS for a while, and I use a variable from the atlas to filter labels, construct geometries, etc. But the atlas variables aren't everywhere in QGIS and I can't make a real filter on a table.
My purpose is to make an atlas with barchart: the atlas coverage filter a layer used for a barchart make with dataplotly. The barchart is included in the atlas by its html. The dataplotly extension seems to have an automatic refresh.

I don't think my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3.10 Dataplotly is included in the Layouts. You may create a bar chart and it will follow the Atlas features and change accordingly.

See an example here: https://twitter.com/ghtmtt/status/1191380049120890880